# android.enableAapt2=false is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

```
The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018.
```

I was using `android.enableAapt2=false` code in the gradle properties for all of my project because if I don't write this preview is not working and app is not running good. I upgraded my Android Studio and then I am getting this error. What can I do for this? Thank you

Comment: Follow the migration guide in the docs.