# Configuration 'compile' with android.enableAapt2

Tags: android, android-studio

When press try again show me some problems.

These are the settings I used in the build.gradle of my application:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.abc.callrecorder'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName '1.1'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.gu:option:1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.onedrivesdk:onedrive-picker-android:v2.0'
    implementation 'com.alimuzaffar.lib:pinentryedittext:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:android-device-names:1.1.4'
    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.AmniX:MaterialPatternllockView:7a45dcaa79'
    implementation 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

These are the setting in build.gradle application:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

These are mistakes :

> The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used
>   anymore. Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning. It
>   will be removed at the end of 2018..
>
> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For
>   more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Comment: You have tagged this as PHP, not sure which tags are more appropriate

Comment: Please, structure the title more into normal question, and add keywords at the beginning of the description with short descriptive text. Please, also check this suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701666/android-enableaapt2-false-is-not-working. Hope you will find a solution. Best!